# Explain query locks

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, locking

Mysql has an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) command that explains execution plan information including join strategies, involved partitions, etc.

Is there a way to see locking strategies for a query that I plan to execute?

Comment: The default locking is [documented in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/internal-locking.html).